# Using camel to route from webapp

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, messaging

I am trying to use camel to route a message from my web app to a queue and I am using a bean reference to grab the message from a function that is run whenever an input is given to the browser. However, camel creates a Null exception when it continues to poll because there isn't always an input every half second. How can I make the camel only pick up the message when there is one to pick up? Browserbean is the function that returns the message from the browser.

Here is my camel route:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="browserBean"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
    <to uri="myBean"/>
    <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
    <to uri="finalBean"/>
    <log message="message: ${body}"/>
</route>
</camelContext>

<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate" />
</camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="myBean" class="com.example.integration.modifier"/>
    <bean id="finalBean" class="com.example.integration.ActionApp"/>
    <bean id="browserBean" class="com.hello.integration.GreetingController"/>

</beans>
```

Here is the stack trace I get every second or so:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         ------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                            Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [browserBean                                                                      ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [jms:queue:testQSource                                                         ] [         0]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
Id                  ID-CO183LTCS06-59664-1403735006145-0-16
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-CO183LTCS06-59664-1403735006145-0-15,          CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
BodyType            null
Body                [Body is null]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.hello.integration.GreetingController.greeting(GreetingController.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
at     org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)
at    org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorPollingConsumer.receive(ProcessorPollingConsumer.java:58)
at    org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorPollingConsumer.receiveNoWait(ProcessorPollingConsumer.java:    66)
at     org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumer.poll(DefaultScheduledPollConsumer.java:4    8)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at     java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown      Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown     Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why not check for a null message then process appropriately?

Comment: I thought about that but I don't know where to start. Do you think you might be able to help me through it?

Comment: Can you show us the code of the GreetingController? I think you need to avoid the NPE there.